# Keep track of result sets for each parameter in a table valued parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression, table-valued-parameters

I have got this fairly complex query with multiple recursive members, which I need to run for a list of values, say for example Product Ids (the query outputs parent id along with all its child ids). How can I print out the result set for each of those values alongside that value itself.

Consider a scenario like below...

```
DECLARE @products table (prdid varchar(40));
Insert INTO @products values('A111'),('B111'),('A123'), ('Z456');

with rec_query as (
                    ---anchor member
                     '
                     '
                    where pid IN @products
                    UNION ALL
                    ---recursive members
                    '
                    '
                  )
```

I want something like

```
select prdid, rec_query.*
```

which would output something similar to below result

A111| its result set
B111| its result set
A123| its result set

Comment: Why can't you just include `pid` inside CTE?

Comment: You mean like join it to `@products` table? I don't think that'll give me desired outcome